# Optimize join in HIVE query: c

Tags: join, hadoop, hive, query-optimization

I would like to know which one is the best way to optimize an HIVE (0.12) query joining two tables among these three possible candidates (and possibly understand why):

```
SELECT * FROM a join b ON (a.id = b.id) WHERE b.dt = "2014-09-01";
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON (a.id = b.id AND b.dt = "2014-09-01") ;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN ( 
     SELECT * FROM b where dt = "2014-09-01" ) c 
ON a.id = c.id ;
```

I have no control on how the tables are stored and partitioned, so my question is more about
general best practices than a specific case. I know for sure that a.id = b.id is only possible when b.dt = '2014-09-01' so I would like to restrict the data that can be joined to improve the speed (b is a huge table).

Reading HIVE documentation I understood that usually it is better that a is the smallest table and b is a (very) large one; I couldn't however understand how the
different queries shown above would behave in terms of performances.

If there is some other way I could use I would like to know about it as well.

Comment: How big is a table, does it fit to memory?

Comment: I would say this particular I am using could, in general no, they won't.

Answer (score 1):

I see that all the three are same in terms of #of MR-jobs , mappers used and explain plan.
By taking care that table a is small enough map-side join optimization is utilised.
by switching the positions of the filter on table b has no effect on the number of mappers used to retrieve data from table b. So is the case even when table b is in the subquery.

The only optimization is partition pruning if table b happens to be partitioned on col dt which I see the only factor to reduce the number of mappers compared to a full table scan otherwise.